# From observation in one column to the sequence in several columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data which look like this:

```
set.seed(100)    
df<- data.frame(exp = c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5), "C", "C"), 
    re = c(rep(seq(1, 5, 1), 2), 1, 2), d = runif(12, 1, 40))
```

For each row in the `exp data.frame` I'd make a sequence of 3 closest `d's`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- arrange(df, exp, re) %>% 
group_by(exp) %>% 
mutate(d1 = d, d2 = lead(d), d3 = lead(d2))
```

and I recieve

```
   exp re         d        d1        d2        d3
1    A  1 25.389088 25.389088  1.233483 27.916293
2    A  2  1.233483  1.233483 27.916293 30.627384
3    A  3 27.916293 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
4    A  4 30.627384 30.627384 17.219979        NA
5    A  5 17.219979 17.219979        NA        NA
6    B  1 25.280619 25.280619  1.468439 28.398679
7    B  2  1.468439  1.468439 28.398679 27.131078
8    B  3 28.398679 28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
9    B  4 27.131078 27.131078  2.971437        NA
10   B  5  2.971437  2.971437        NA        NA
11   C  1  9.892981  9.892981 21.860425        NA
12   C  2 21.860425 21.860425        NA        NA
```

I do not like the `NA's`. If there is `NA` in a row, it should look like the last full sequence of `d1, d2, d3`. For example there is `NA` in row 4 and 5 in `d3` so the `d1, d2, d3` values in this row should be replaced by the values from the row 3
I made `for`loops to make a replacement but they take a lot of time with big data sets. Can someone think a way to make it in `dplyr`

The expected output is:

```
 exp re         d        d1        d2        d3
1    A  1 25.389088 25.389088  1.233483 27.916293
2    A  2  1.233483  1.233483 27.916293 30.627384
3    A  3 27.916293 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
4    A  4 30.627384 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
5    A  5 17.219979 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
6    B  1 25.280619 25.280619  1.468439 28.398679
7    B  2  1.468439  1.468439 28.398679 27.131078
8    B  3 28.398679 28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
9    B  4 27.131078 28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
10   B  5  2.971437  28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
11   C  1  9.892981  9.892981 21.860425        0
12   C  2 21.860425 9.892981 21.86042        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `mutate` step in OP's code, we can use `mutate_each` to replace the `NA` values in columns 'd1' to 'd3'.  We create a condition that `if` the number of elements is greater than 2, we `replace` the elements from position 4 onwards (`which(row_number() >3`) with the third element (`.[3L]`) or `else` we replicate the first element with the number of elements in that group (`rep.[1L], n())`).  For the 'd3', there will be `NA` elements for exp 'C', which can replaced by 0 in the next `mutate`.

```
arrange(df, exp, re) %>% 
      group_by(exp) %>% 
      mutate(d1=d, d2=lead(d), d3=lead(d2)) %>% 
      mutate_each(funs(if(all(n()>2)) replace(., which(row_number()>3),
                .[3L]) else rep(.[1L], n())), d1:d3) %>% 
      mutate(d3= replace(d3, is.na(d3), 0))

#   exp re         d        d1        d2        d3
#1    A  1 25.389088 25.389088  1.233483 27.916293
#2    A  2  1.233483  1.233483 27.916293 30.627384
#3    A  3 27.916293 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
#4    A  4 30.627384 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
#5    A  5 17.219979 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
#6    B  1 25.280619 25.280619  1.468439 28.398679
#7    B  2  1.468439  1.468439 28.398679 27.131078
#8    B  3 28.398679 28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
#9    B  4 27.131078 28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
#10   B  5  2.971437 28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
#11   C  1  9.892981  9.892981 21.860425  0.000000
#12   C  2 21.860425  9.892981 21.860425  0.000000
```

---

Or we could use `shift` from the devel version of `data.table`, i.e. `v1.9.5`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), `order` by the 'exp', and 're' columns.  We group by the 'exp', do `shift` on 'd', specify `n=0:2`, and `type='lead'` to get the 3 new columns ('tmp').  Create a logical index ('i1') based on the last column of 'tmp' (`is.na(tmp[[3]])`).  Create a numeric index ('i2') by taking the cumulative sum of elements that are not NA (`!i1`) and add (`+`) the `TRUE` values of groups that have only `NA` for 'd3' column (`all(i1)`). Loop the 'tmp' columns with `lapply`, use the 'i2' as index to extract the rows.  Finally, change the `NA` values in 'd3' to 0.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df)[order(exp,re), paste0('d', 1:3) := {
                  tmp <- shift(d, 0:2, type='lead')
                  i1 <- is.na(tmp[[3]])
                  i2 <- cumsum(!i1) + all(i1) 
                  lapply(tmp, function(x) x[i2])
                  }, by = exp]
df[is.na(d3), d3:=0]
df
#   exp re         d        d1        d2        d3
# 1:   A  1 25.389088 25.389088  1.233483 27.916293
# 2:   A  2  1.233483  1.233483 27.916293 30.627384
# 3:   A  3 27.916293 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
# 4:   A  4 30.627384 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
# 5:   A  5 17.219979 27.916293 30.627384 17.219979
# 6:   B  1 25.280619 25.280619  1.468439 28.398679
# 7:   B  2  1.468439  1.468439 28.398679 27.131078
# 8:   B  3 28.398679 28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
# 9:   B  4 27.131078 28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
#10:   B  5  2.971437 28.398679 27.131078  2.971437
#11:   C  1  9.892981  9.892981 21.860425  0.000000
#12:   C  2 21.860425  9.892981 21.860425  0.000000
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(exp = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C"), re = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L), d = c(25.389088, 1.233483, 27.916293, 30.627384, 
17.219979, 25.280619, 1.468439, 28.398679, 27.131078, 2.971437, 
9.892981, 21.860425)), .Names = c("exp", "re", "d"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"),
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @akrun. Do you think it is possible to create a program that will account on number of rows in the particular `exp`? I mean if I have a new data set that have f.ex 2, 7, 8 , 10 , 20 observations per `exp` than the program is not perfect as it replace all rows  that in the plot that are > than specified row number by specified line.

Comment: @Mateusz1981 Can you post that as a new question so that it becomes more clear?